# Regex.replace and TrimEnd function in one

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, trim

I seem to have hit mental block and am hoping someone could point me in the right direction. I have a csv file which has numerous comma's (random) in between values, I have some code which deals with this issue where it replaces two comma's into a single one etc. Look Below:

```
        using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader(tbFilePathName.Text))
        {
            string AllLines;
            string newLines;

            //This skips the first line.
            AllLines = r.ReadLine();

            //Reads all the lines to the end.
            AllLines = r.ReadToEnd();

            //This replaces all the instances of a double comma into a single comma. Effectively getting all the data into one column of the csv.
            newLines = Regex.Replace(AllLines, ",{2,}", ",").Trim(',');

            rtbViewLines.AppendText(newLines);

            r.Close();
```

However i want to be able to delete the comma at the end of every line leaving only comma's present within the line. how can i do this together with the function below?

```
 newLines = Regex.Replace(AllLines, ",{2,}", ",").Trim(',');
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of doing r.ReadToEnd() loop through lines and remove trailing commas there

old

```
//Reads all the lines to the end.
AllLines = r.ReadToEnd();
```

new

```
//Reads all the lines to the end.
while (r.Peek() >= 0)
{
    AllLines += r.ReadLine().TrimEnd(',');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know that you can do it in one replace statement but another way would be to split and re-join:

```
newLines = Sting.Join(
               AllLines.Split(new [] {','},StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
              ,",");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a positive lookbehind to find commas that are preceded by a comma, or the commas at the end of the string:

```
newLines = Regex.Replace(AllLines, "(?<=,),+|,+$", "", RegexOptions.Multiline);
```

Comment: Thanks, this doesn't seem to remove the comma at the end of the each line, i get the same results as the original line of code.

Comment: @Rg786: I see, you have all the lines in the same string. Add the `Multiline` option to make `$` mean end of line instead of end of string.